# Movie where a man's tongue gets longer and longer

Tags: story-identification, movie

I’m looking for a movie that I had seen in the early 2000’s and it looked like a modern time movie. Two men were sitting in chairs across from each other. It looked like night and they seemed to be in the middle of the street. No cars went by during this. One of the men opens his mouth and his tongue starts coming out and as it’s coming out it gets longer and longer. They seemed pretty relaxed.

Comment: We have to identify this one if only to avoid seeing it by accident.

Comment: IMDB has a tag for long tongue; https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=long-tongue